# How to automatically extract build artifacts from a docker container keeping ownership of the calling process?

Tags: docker, build

I'm writing some automated build scripts which use a docker container as a build environment.

One thing that's been bugging me is finding a way to extract the build artifacts from the container and retaining the user ownership of the calling process.

Usually this is automatic; when a process creates a file, the file is owned by the user running the process.  But where a process invokes a docker container, the container runs as a different user (often `root`).  I see no simple way for the container to run as the same user as the calling process.  So if I map a local directory when invoking docker (`docker run --volume $(pwd)/target:/target`) then when the build script in the image writes it's files, they will turn up in the host's build directory owned by `root`.

The other alternative I can see is to run the container, wait for it to complete, then use `docker cp` to extract the build artifacts.  The trouble with this is I don't see a way to run a container to completion and *then* get the container ID of the recently created container.

Is there a common way to automatically / programmatically extract build artifacts from a docker container keeping the ownership of the calling process?

Comment: What about setting the user?   Map your userid/groupid to any user inside docker.

Comment: @abestrad that might be okay, but not if it needs to be hard coded.  The intent of this question is to have a complete build process that "transparently" leaving the artifact behind owned by the user of the calling process, whichever user that is.

Comment: `docker run` takes a `--user` option.  The numeric user ID needs to match what's on the host, but there's often not a need for that user to "exist" inside the container's `/etc/passwd` file.